# Redirect page without runnin java script in php

Tags: javascript, php

first.php

```
<?php
   $file_name='1.pdf';
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.open('pdf/<?php echo $file_name;?>','_blank')
<script>
<?php
header('location:second.php');
?>
```

second.php

```
<?php
echo 'Welcome..!';

?>
```

In this above coding i have to run first.php it can't open pdf file new tab directly goto this second.php.

anyone have a solution for my problem.i have to view pdf file in new tab on this time first.php redirect to second.php.

Comment: Do the redirect in javascript.

Comment: how to do that pls give some examples

Comment: `location.href = '/your/url/here';`

Comment: Opps. Sorry i didint see @Bulk introduce the location comment. That's correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the redirect with javascript.

```
<?php
$file_name='1.pdf';
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.open('pdf/<?php echo $file_name;?>','_blank');
location.href = 'second.php';
</script>
```